# Python: format() method specifying the format code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
>>> 
>>> "i = {0:10}".format(10)
'i =         10'
>>> 
>>> "i = {0:10d}".format(10)
'i =         10'
>>>
```

Whether I use format code `d` or not the output appears to be the same.

So can I assume that I can always omit format code `d`?

Update:  I already know various ways to format string. I am looking for an explanation of the aforementioned behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the format mini-language docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

The available integer presentation types are:

```
Type    Meaning

'd'     Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.

None    The same as 'd'.
```

So yes, for `int`s, including or omitting the `d` doesn't matter. That said, including the `d` will cause non-integer types (those that don't support `d`, which is most) to raise an exception if you try to format them with it. If you want `str`, `float` and other times to fail loudly (so you can fix the code), use the `d`.

Comment: That's extremely helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One is explicit and the other is "implicit" (Not really).
When you are using the `d` format, you are telling Python that you are expecting an integer to be given to the format and it will raise an error if that requirement is not satisfied.
While without the `d`, Python will just do `str(val)` on the given value, without attempting to validate it first and check that this value is an integer.

To sum up, if you want to make sure that the given value is an integer, you should consider using the `d`, to prompt an error when a non integer value is supplied, otherwise, just use format without it.